# What's the difference between using QWebSocket with a URL "wss://..." and QSslSocket in Qt?

Tags: qt, ssl, qsslsocket

New to Qt. I'm having trouble understanding the difference between using QWebSocket with a secure url, "wss://..." and QSslSocket. Which one of these is necessary to establish secure communication with a server in Qt? Or is something different entirely?

The Qt example ["Secure Socket Client Example"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-securesocketclient-example.html) uses a normal QWebSocket with "wss://..." but the documentation and what seems intuitive for secure comm is using QSslSocket. Which one should I be using for a secure comm client implementation?

I'm securing my QWebSockets, which are not secured currently, and trying to understand the alternatives and best implementation for secure comm.

Comment: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-October/013710.html

Comment: "wss" is the URI scheme for WebSocket over TLS (the not so new name for SSL). Just like "https" is HTTP over TLS. So in fact you are using a secure channel (the spec can be found here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-11.1.2).

Comment: I saw that post, but it doesn't really bring up using a normal web socket vs the QSslSocket and the benefits. 

Rolf - I'm aware wss is secure, but what's the difference in using wss with a QWebSocket vs QSslSocket? If the communication is secured with wss over a QWebSocket, is there any advantage to moving to QSslSocket?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on stackoverflow.
If you need WSS protocol you may use `QWebSocket`. If you need HTTPS server you may use `QSslSocket` and `QTcpServer`. Or ready to use project e.g. [github.com/azadkuh/qhttp](https://github.com/azadkuh/qhttp), branch dev.

Of course you may implement `QWebSocket` yourself but only `open` function contains about 2 pages of code and is based on `QSslSocket` and `QTcpSocket`.

Sorry for so late answer but one year ago I wasn't interesting in this.